# XNA What does Game.Services mean?

Tags: c#, xna

I want to learn more about ContentManager and many more about XNA, so if you know about some good website, please share it with me. I'd love to know details about how everything works. But my question here is: ContentManager(IServiceProvider, String) - what exactly is IServiceProvider and what does it do and as an example of this constructor I saw Game.Services being used, what does that contain? I'm trying to learn about managing my resources and I would like to know what does it mean for my ContentManager when I create instance like this :

```
ContentManager contentManager = new ContentManager(Game.Services, path );
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few blog posts that can help you with your research. Google is your friend!

http:// blog.nuclex-games.com/tutorials/xna/components-and-services/
http:// itspaulsblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/xna-game-services.html
http://game-programmers.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/services-and-game-components-in-xna.html

Also, I think your IServiceProvider question may have already been answered before. Check it out man. Do a little research of your own before asking for help!
[Why use services (IServiceProvider)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802090/why-use-services-iserviceprovider)

Hope this is useful!